# Asynchronous processes and the Object Oriented paradigm

Tags: actionscript-3, asynchronous, remote-access, object-oriented-analysis

One of the object oriented principles is the encapsulation of code. Each object knows how to implement its methods. Objects only know how to call and how to get the result of other objects' methods.

I don't see how to implement this principle when an object method makes calls to remote services.

For example :

```
Class A{

    method1(){
    ...
    }


    method2(){
        callRemote(receiveAnswer);
    }

    receiveAnswer(answer){
    ...
    }

}

Class B{

    main(){

        A a = new A();

        a.method2();

        a.method1();

    }

}
```

method2() in class A needs receiveAnswer() to complete itself => part of its logic is inside receiveAnswer(). And receiveAnswer() is executed only after the remote service sends an answer.

In class B, the main() executes a.method2() and then a.method1() directly after, without waiting for the remote service to answer method2().

Very often, method1() needs the complete execution of method2() (including the processing of the remote service answer) in order to be executed correctly.

Should I externalize the call to the remote service in class B (which seems not very suitable because in that case I would expose an object logic to the outside)? Is there any other way of doing it ?

Thanks ;)

PS: I'm coding in ActionScript 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I externalize the call to the remote service in class B

You shouldn't. For async processes you should use callbacks or observers: [EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html), [AS3Signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals), or simple function callback.

So it reads:

```
Class B{

    main(){

        var a: A = new A();

        //EventDispatcher
        //a.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

        //Signals
        //a.complete.add(onComplete);

        //Callback
        //a.method(onComplete);

        a.startAsyncProcess();
    }

    onComplete(){
        //Magic with a result
    }        
}
```